# Sharepoint FAST Search query fails when StartItem is larger than 100000

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

## The Problem

I've got a FAST Search query that returns more than **100000** results. I am trying to get the results in chunks of 5000, like this:

```cs
var queryManager = SharedQueryManager.GetInstance(this.Page).QueryManager;
queryManager[0][0].ItemsPerPage = 5000;
queryManager[0][0].StartItem = 1;
queryManager[0][0].TrimDuplicates = false;
queryManager[0][0].RequestedProperties = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection() { "title" };
var results = queryManager[0][0].GetResults(queryManager);
```

It works fine if StartItem is lower than 100000. But **it fails** as soon as I try:

```cs
queryManager[0][0].StartItem = 100001;
```

I am getting an exception: `The search request was unable to execute on FAST Search Server.`, with inner exception being (not very helpful): `The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.`

## Things I've tried

I suppose this is a configuration issue, as it happens only right after the 100000 mark. It does not seem to be a timeout or too much data being transferred.

I have tried changing the Search Service Application configuration (`Config:qp_MaxResultsReturned`), like suggested [here](http://www.silver-it.com/node/97)
but with no luck.

There is also a workaround suggesting that I could sort the results by the created date, and add additional filtering by date (that way I would always receive max 5000 results), but I think it is a bit ugly.

I have used the [FAST Search for Sharepoint 2010 Query Logger](http://fs4splogger.codeplex.com/releases/view/98451) to log the query that fails. Strangely, the logged response contains search results over the 100000 mark and no indication of an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the "maxoffset" it is located in the "fdispatch.addon" file:

%FASTSEARCH%/etc/config_data/RTSearch/webcluster/fdispatch.addon

Then, restart search "nctrl restart search-1"